# yum equivalent to apt-get upgrade vs apt-get dist-upgrade?

Tags: linux, apt, yum

I'm a *.deb guy and I feel quite uncomfortable while managing rpms.

I'm used to run `apt-get upgrade` in my debian based servers for "normal" upgrades and `apt-get dist-upgrade` for *allowing* kernel upgrades or allowing new major package versions upgrades.

In the CentOS servers I admin, I would like to have a similar feature, however man yum doesn't seem to offer such behaviour. And the differences between `yum update` and `yum upgrade` seems to be not what I'm looking for.

So far my best approach is to add and remove the following setting in `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
exclude=kernel*
```

There must be a better approach. Every suggestion will be welcome.

**EDITED:**

The yum's man page description of them and the `--obsoletes` flag is a bit cryptic for me. So let me reword what I understand from it: Do I have to understand that `yum update` won't install a new kernel because it would mean marking as obsolete the current one? Can I assume that `yum upgrade` does the same or almost the same than `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

**EDITED 2**

What I like best from `apt-get upgrade` is that it tells me which packages remain retained so I can act accordingly; either with `apt-get dist-upgrade` or with explicit `apt-get install package`.

So after thinking a bit my best approach **at this moment** will be: disable the *obsoletes* setting in yum.conf (as described by Steven Pritchard in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/298158/329431)) and run at first `yum update`. Once all the updates are installed, run a second `yum update --obsoletes` to check which packages have been retained and act in function of its results.

Will that work?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`yum update` originally just did upgrades of packages to new versions.  If, for example, `foo-awesome` obsoleted `foo`, `yum update` wouldn't offer to upgrade from `foo` to `foo-awesome`.  Adding the `--obsoletes` flag to `yum update` made it do the extra checks to also offer that upgrade path.  `yum upgrade` was added as (essentially) an alias for `yum --obsoletes update`.  Since this is the behavior that almost everyone wants all of the time, the configuration option `obsoletes=1` was added to the default `/etc/yum.conf`, making `yum update` and `yum upgrade` equivalent on any recent, stock, Fedora/RHEL/CentOS/etc.

If you want to avoid kernel updates when you're running `yum update`, you can just do `yum --exclude=kernel* update`.  If you want automatic updates on, but you want to avoid automatic kernel upgrades, then adding the exclude to yum.conf is probably the right answer.

There probably isn't a Right Answer for your question.  RHEL and RHEL-based distributions don't have the same philosophy as the Debian developers when it comes to updates, so the tools don't encourage the same sorts of behavior.

Comment: +1 Steven; I guess that there won't be a *right answer*, that's why I want as much feedback as possible. Your answer is excellent. Let me wait for other people approaches :-)

Comment: See my **EDITED 2**, so far I believe that is a good approach to mimic apt-get behavior.

Comment: You can also add excludes to the yum.conf file.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
# yum upgrade yum kernel
# yum -y upgrade
```